# Show available slots within time range taking into account already booked slots

Tags: php, datetime

This script checks if a 60 min slot is available within a time range taking into account already booked slots.
It works fine for the first already booked slot but does not take into account the second. Also if I change the first booked slot to 12:10 it will not detect it.

Basically, the idea is if there is a 60 min slot between the range and the already booked slots to show it.

**For example,**, if we have a range `9:00` to `15:00` and we have two booked slots from `11:10` and `14:00`, to return available slots from `9:00, 10:00 and 12:10`

```
$start_time = '2022-10-21 09:00:00';  //start time as string
$end_time = '2022-10-21 15:00:00';  //end time as string
$booked = ['2022-10-21 12:00:00','2022-10-21 13:00:00']; //booked slots as arrays
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$start_time); //create date time objects
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$end_time);  //create date time objects
$time1 = $start;
$count = 0;  //number of slots
$out = array();   //array of slots 
for($i = $start; $i<$end;)  //for loop 
{
    $avoid = false; 
    $t1 = date_timestamp_get($i);
    $t2 = $t1+(60*60);

    for($k=0;$k<sizeof($booked);$k+=2)  //if booked hour
    {
        $st = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$booked[$k]);
        $en = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$booked[$k+1]);
          
        if( $t1 >= date_timestamp_get($st) && $t2 <= date_timestamp_get($en)  )
        $avoid = true;   //yes. booked
    }
    $slots =[ $i->format('H:i'),$i->modify("+60 minutes")->format('H:i')];
    if(!$avoid && $i<$end)  //if not booked and less than end time
    {
        $count++;  
        array_push($out,$slots);  //add slot to array
    }
}
var_dump($out);   //array out
```

**Here is link to sandbox**
https://onlinephp.io/c/b0b77

**Additional information**

Let's say that we have a free time frame from `10:00 until 13:00`. What the script should return is `10:00`, `11:00`, and `12:00` as possibilities if the time slot is `60 min`.

If the timeslot is `45 min`. for example, it should return `10:00`, `10:45`, `11:30`, and `12:15`.

So, the possible variants should start from the first possible option increasing with the time slot (`45, 60, or whatever time slot is set`)

The slot cannot start from `10:12, 10:44, or another custom time`

**The Solutions**

Both solutions below by `Salman A` and `Jim` are working as expected. Just use a little bit of a different approach.

**Overlapping bookings** - Update provided

If you have overlapping bookings as suggested by `Salman A` we have to first merge them and then send unique intervals only.
I did it with that function

```
function mergeBookings($ranges)
{
    $retVal = [];
    //sort date ranges by begin time
    usort($ranges, function ($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['start'], $b['start']);
    });

    $currentRange = [];
    foreach ($ranges as $range) {
        // bypass invalid value
        if ($range['start'] >= $range['end']) {
            continue;
        }
        //fill in the first element
        if (empty($currentRange)) {
            $currentRange = $range;
            continue;
        }

        if ($currentRange['end'] < $range['start']) {
            $retVal[] = $currentRange;
            $currentRange = $range;
        } elseif ($currentRange['end'] < $range['end']) {
            $currentRange ['end'] = $range['end'];
        }
    }

    if ($currentRange) {
        $retVal[] = $currentRange;
    }

    return $retVal;
}
```

Then just use the function before sending the $booked array to the script. Like this

```
$booked = mergeBookings($booked);
```

Comment: Couple of things to clarify before I can attempt to help. Can a slot be booked at any minute past the hour e.g. 11:07, 11:38 etc? And are all booked slots for 1 hour e.g. 11:07 - 12:07?

Comment: @BenPlummer, I have added more information in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Time slot for booking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220642/create-time-slot-for-booking)

Comment: also, if it helps: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882645/check-availability-of-time-with-time-slots-in-php; 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497123/check-timeslot-is-between-another-time-slot

Comment: @OMiShah, it does not include the already booked time slots. Also, not showing the all available slots between the available timeframes

Comment: @lStoilov if start time is 09:00, time slot is 45 minutes and there is a booking that does not correspond to 45 minute e.g. from 09:00 to 09:30. What would be the first avalable slot?

Comment: @SalmanA, it will be at the moment the existing booking ends, in this case 09:30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with simple nested loops if booked dates are sorted. Notice the pattern in the data; end date from one row and start date from next row form an *available* range, in which you create the slots:

```
$start_time =                                        '2022-10-21 09:00:00';
$booked = array(
    array('start' => '2022-10-21 11:10:00', 'end' => '2022-10-21 12:10:00'),
    array('start' => '2022-10-21 14:00:00', 'end' => '2022-10-21 15:00:00')
);
$end_time =          '2022-10-21 15:00:00';
$slot_size = 60;
// data must be sorted by date
usort($booked, function($a, $b) {
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $a['start']) <=> DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $b['start']);
});
$interval = new DateInterval('PT' . $slot_size . 'M');
$result = array();
for ($i = 0, $j = count($booked); $i <= $j; $i++) {
    // loop count + 1 times
    // first and last iterations are special
    $range_start = $i === 0 ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_time) : DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $booked[$i - 1]['end']);
    $range_end = $i < $j ? DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $booked[$i]['start']) : DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_time);
    $t1 = (clone $range_start);
    $t2 = (clone $range_start)->add($interval);
    while ($t2 <= $range_end) {
        $result[] = array('start' => $t1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'end' => $t2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $t1->add($interval);
        $t2->add($interval);
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I just found one interesting case where the logic fails. Suppose you have a booked time with a longer frame that overlaps with another booking. then it will return the wrong free slots. example `$booked = array(
 array('start' => '2022-10-21 10:00:00', 'end' => '2022-10-21 15:00:00'),
    array('start' => '2022-10-21 11:10:00', 'end' => '2022-10-21 12:10:00'),
    
);` Here is a demo [link]https://onlinephp.io/c/d94bd

Comment: The logic assumes no overlap. If you have overlaps in bookings you could merge overlapping intervals after sorting but before the loop. Merging cn easily be done if arrays are sorted (hint: if start time of nth range is less than end time of n-1th range then you have an overlap; combine the two ranges).

Comment: I see. Can you give me an example with the current script?

Comment: I think I did it. Also updated the initial question with this information.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you need to implement is as follows (I'm implementing it in pseudo-code for now):

```
booking_length <- 1h //1 hour, you can set this to something else
for dt <- start, dt <- end - booking_length, d <- d + booking_length
    b <- closest booking after d
    if (d + booking_length < b) then
        bookings.add(d)
    else
        d <- b + booking_length
    else
end for
```

The reason as of why I didn't implement this in PHP was that I did not have enough time to do so at the time of this writing. Let me know if this is not clear yet and whether you need PHP code.

Comment: yes, please I am looking for a PHP code. Thanks

Comment: @lStoilov was about to implement it, but I have seen there is an accepted answer which already has it, so I upvoted it instead.

Comment: Absolutely, Salman A was fast and the answer was good... Also, Jim had an interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.dateperiod.php) combined with [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.dateinterval.php) to create ranges or slots to which you can then check if the slot intersects with any of the booked slots:

```php
/**
 * Create DatePeriod with start time & end times
 */
function createBookedDateTime(
    string $startDate,
    string $endDate
): DatePeriod {
    $start = new DateTime($startDate);
    $end = new DateTime($endDate);
    return new DatePeriod(
        $start,
        $start->diff($end),
        $end
    );
}

/**
 * Check if any of the booking values, previously added slot, or end of the
 * availability period intersect with the currently checked slot.
 */
function isAvailable(
    array $bookingArray,
    DateTime $dtToCheck,
    ?DatePeriod $prevSlot,
    DateInterval $bookingLength,
    DateTime $availabilityEnd
) {
    $isBooked = false;
    $intersectsPrevious = false;
    $dtPeriodToCheck = new DatePeriod(
        $dtToCheck,
        $bookingLength,
        (clone $dtToCheck)->add($bookingLength)
    );
    /** @var DatePeriod $bookedDt */
    foreach($bookingArray as $bookedDt) {
        if(
            (
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getStartDate() >= $bookedDt->getStartDate() &&
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getStartDate() < $bookedDt->getEndDate()
            ) ||
            (
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getEndDate() >= $bookedDt->getStartDate() &&
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getEndDate() < $bookedDt->getEndDate()
            )
        ) {
            $isBooked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($prevSlot instanceof DatePeriod) {
        $intersectsPrevious =
            (
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getStartDate() >= $prevSlot->getStartDate() &&
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getStartDate() < $prevSlot->getEndDate()
            ) ||
            (
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getEndDate() >= $prevSlot->getStartDate() &&
                $dtPeriodToCheck->getEndDate() < $prevSlot->getEndDate()
            );
    }
    return $isBooked === false && $intersectsPrevious === false &&
        $dtPeriodToCheck->getEndDate() <= $availabilityEnd;
}

// Length of booking
$bookingLength = new DateInterval('PT1H');

// DatePeriod array of already booked slots
$booked = [
    createBookedDateTime('2022-10-21 11:10:00', '2022-10-21 12:15:00'),
    createBookedDateTime('2022-10-21 12:15:00', '2022-10-21 12:45:00'),
];

// The range of time available for booking divided into slots by
// the $bookingLength interval.
$availStart = new DateTime('2022-10-21 09:00:00');
$availEnd = new DateTime('2022-10-21 15:00:00');
$availability = new DatePeriod($availStart, new DateInterval('PT5M'), $availEnd);

// Array of available booking slots
$availableToBook = array();
$prevSlot = null;

// Loop to find available booking slots
/** @var DateTime $available */
foreach($availability as $available) {

    if(isAvailable($booked, $available, $prevSlot, $bookingLength, $availEnd)) {
        $availableToBook []= $prevSlot = new DatePeriod(
            $available,
            $bookingLength,
            (clone $available)->add($bookingLength)
        );
    }

}

var_dump($availableToBook);
```

Here I have created a function which creates a `DatePeriod` for each of the booked slots by using the start & end date & time.

The second function, `isAvailable`, is called within the loop to check if the time slot intersects with any of the booked entries, previously added slot, or the end of the availability period. If not, it is added to the `$availableToBook` array.

You can change the booking length by altering `$bookingLength` to whatever you want (it is set to one hour). You can change it to 15 minutes (`PT15M`), 30 minutes (`PT30M`), 45 minutes (`PT45M`), or whatever time length you want.

Comment: The solution seems good, however, it kind of presumes that all existing bookings are the same length (PT1S for example). So it will fail if we have a booking for 30 min that start at 12:10

Comment: @lStoilov `createBookedTime` can easily be modified to add an end `DateTime` rather than using the interval. The code and your question didn't seem to indicate the bookings were different lengths (just showed an array of start times).

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. Sorry. What I wrote was "So, the possible variants should start from the first possible option increasing with the time slot (45, 60, or whatever time slot is set)", which means that the bookings can be of different lengths, depending on what was set during execution of the booking. But the next loop might be a different length.

Comment: @lStoilov If bookings can be different lengths, how would we know when the available slots are? It would be any minute within the available time. Is there a set or array slot lengths that can be chosen?

Comment: The available slot starts from the moment the booked slots end and the is a space for it. Look at @Salman A solution, it works exactly like that. As he mentioned ...It is a simple nested loop.

Comment: Yes, now it is working as expected. Thanks!